# Is there any way to send an email from a Gmail plus address?

Tags: gmail

I know that I can sign up to a service using user+foo@example.com, the question I have is how can I send an email from this same address?

Comment: See Also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6730/how-can-i-send-email-from-a-plus-address-from-a-different-account-in-gmail

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes.  Add it the same way you'd add any other email to send from:

1. Click on Settings in the upper right.
2. Click on Accounts and Import.
3. In the "Send mail as" section click "Add another email address you own".
4. Add the "plus email" and finish the setup.
5. Compose an email and select the custom "plus email" in the From dropdown.

Comment: For reference, here's Google's page explaining how to add a custom from address: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370

Comment: Would you recommend checking the "Treat as alias" checkbox? The provided help article https://support.google.com/a/answer/1710338 is not easy to understand in this context.

Comment: That thing is pretty hard to understand, agreed -- but I think in almost every case of someone using a "plus address" it would be desirable to "Treat as an alias", so I would say leave it checked. The only time to not use that, from my interpretation, is if you are sending mail as someone else (as an assistant, or helicopter parent perhaps?) and you really want to be able to see it as a distinct usage scenario.

Answer (score 7):

It is officially not supported but there is a workaround using the "send mail as"-feature:

You need to go to the `Settings` tab and click `Accounts and Import`. Click there `Sent mail from another address` and enter your plus e-mail address. Click `Next Step` and the plus mail address is ready for use. You need to do this for every address you want to use.

Comment: So you have to do this for every +address you want to use?

Comment: It doesn't send verification for "plus" emails.

Comment: @Senseful Yes. It is a much requested feature from Google but its not implemented yet.

Comment: Regarding your edit:  Are you sure?  I went through the steps as I was typing up my answer and I received the email and it has the +address as the sent-from address.

Comment: @rchern sure? I just tried it but it it just said `  You cannot send e-mail from {mail}+plus@gmail.com`.

Comment: @neo:  Positive.  Like I said, I did the steps as I went through them.  I sent the email just to make sure it really said it was from the +address.  Google Apps limitation?  I'm doing it with a regular gmail address.

Comment: @rchern me, too. It was once possibly for me (hence the answer), but it's not working anymore.

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake. I use GMail in Germany and because of trademark issues it is not allowed for them to use the term `GMail` for their service, instead it is named `Google Mail` over here. Nonetheless receiving mails via `{name}@gmail.com` is still possible. Sending somehow not anymore. Using `{name}+plus@googlemail.com` actually worked.

Comment: Tradmark issues?

Comment: @Arlen Beiler: Yes, there is https://www.gmail.de/ since many years (but nobody knows it actually). It was the same problem in the UK and its still the case in Poland.

Comment: Could you give me a link to a news article or something? I don't see why there would be trademark issues. I live in the use, FYI.

Comment: @Arlen Beiler: http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/news/2007/01/8741.ars this is only the case in Germany. No worries for the US folk ;-)

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks for this answer