# How can I send email from a GMail alias (one with the "+" symbol) address from a different account in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I know that I can [send email from the same account with a plus address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/is-there-any-way-to-send-an-email-from-a-gmail-plus-address), but how can I do the same from another account or device?

When I try to use a plus address, it ignores it and sends the mail from the real address.

Comment: See Also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6746/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-alias-in-google-apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. [Set up the plus address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/is-there-any-way-to-send-an-email-from-a-gmail-plus-address) on the original account (even though you won't be using it directly from that interface).
2. Add the account's SMTP information, using the following settings:

   - Email: Your plus address (user+sample@example.com)
   - Username: Either your plus address (user+sample@example.com) or your base address (user@example.com) will work. In fact, it completely ignores anything afer the `+`, so even an address that wasn't added as a "Send As" in step 1 (user+foo@example.com) will work.
   - Password: The password for user@example.com.

If you don't do the first step, the account isn't permitted to send mail via that plus address and any attempts made at sending via that plus address (user+sample@example.com) will actually be sent from the base address (user@example.com).

Note: the plus address will appear in most headers when the email is sent (e.g. `Return-Path`, `From`, `Received`) but the base address will still be shown in the `Sender` field. However, most clients should show the `From` field and hide the `Sender` field from the user.