# How can I send mail from an alias in Google Apps?

Tags: google-apps-email

I'm using Google Apps Standard.

I created an alias (alias@example.com) for my account (user@example.com). When people email me at alias@example.com, it correctly arrives at my user@example.com email address.

How can I send mail using this alias address? That is, the alias@example.com address should appear as the sender to whomever I email, and my real address (user@example.com) should never be revealed to them.

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6730/how-can-i-send-email-from-a-plus-address-from-a-different-account-in-gmail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you must add it as a Send As email on the account where the alias is defined. This must be done even if you are going to use a separate account to email from this address. This is [exactly the same behavior as sending from a plus address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6730/how-can-i-send-email-from-a-plus-address-from-a-different-account-in-gmail).

For the authentication, you should use:

- Email: Your alias (e.g. alias@example.com)
- Username: Your email address (e.g. user@example.com). Note: this is different from using a plus address in that you cannot use the alias as the username, you must use the real email address.
- Password: Your email address' password